# Calling jQuery function on link with variable id click

Tags: jquery

Hi I have following html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Docket No. #</th>
            <th>Del Date</th>
            <th>Box</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Update</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dsr-data">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to define jQuery function to call the functions updateStatus and deleteStatus in jQuery? I have written below code but its not work which is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function()
{
    $.getJSON("DsrList.php",{page:"dsrlist",request:  
    "dsrData"},function(json)
    {
        var response = json.response;
        var screen = response.screen;
        var session = response.session;
        var branch = session.branch;
        var username = session.username;
        var dsrNo = session.dsr_no;
        var dsrData = session.dsrData;
        if(screen == "dsrlist"){
            $("#dsr-branch").text(branch);
            $("#dsr-user").text(username);
            $("#dsr_no").text(dsrNo);
            $("#dsr-data").html(dsrData);
        }
    });
});

$(function(){

$.fn.extend({
 uploadStatus: function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 id = id.replace("upload-", "");
    alert(id);
 }
});

$.fn.extend({
 deleteStatus: function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 id = id.replace("delete-", "");
    alert(id);
 }
});

$('.action').on('click', function(e) {
if($(this).hasClass('upload')) {
  $(this).uploadStatus();
} else {
  $(this).deleteStatus();
 }
});

});
});
</script>
```

DsrList.php is populating following data:

```
<tr>
 <td>812210</td>
 <td>03-12-2016</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>out for delivery</td>
 <td>
   <a class="action upload" id="upload-1">
    <img src="img/upload.png" alt="Upload"></a>
  <a class="action delete" id="delete-1">
    <img src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>812211</td>
 <td>03-12-2016</td>
 <td>20</td>
 <td>out for delivery</td>
 <td>
   <a class="action upload" id="upload-2">
    <img src="img/upload.png" alt="Upload"></a>
   <a class="action delete" id="delete-2">
    <img src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Which $("#dsr-data").html(dsrData); assigning in .

But on click of update / delete images I am getting no alert.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `onclick` attribute in HTML, as you're using jQuery's extend property you can take use of jQuery properly, you can add classes `delete` and `upload` with the class `action` in common.

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<a class="action upload" id="upload-1">
    <img src="img/upload.png">
</a>
<a class="action delete" id="delete-1">
    <img src="img/delete.png">
</a>
```

and simply use jQuery's `onClick` event handler and `hasClass` method to know the clicked block is for upload or delete. For better understanding see the code below:

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function(){

  $.fn.extend({
     uploadStatus: function () {
        alert('Upload Block Clicked : id = ' + $(this).attr('id'));
     }
  });
  
  $.fn.extend({
     deleteStatus: function () {
        alert('Delete Block Clicked: id = ' + $(this).attr('id'));
     }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.action', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('upload')) {
   $(this).uploadStatus();
    } else {
      $(this).deleteStatus();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Docket No. #</th>
      <th>Del Date</th>
      <th>Box</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dsr-data">
    <tr>
      <td>812210</td>
      <td>2016-12-03</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>out for delivery</td>
      <td>
        <a class="action upload" id="upload-1">
        <img src="img/upload.png" alt="Upload">
        </a>
        <a class="action delete" id="delete-1">
        <img src="img/delete.png" alt="Delete">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me. Your code is working independently. But when clubbed with my code. It is not working. My table rows are dynamically created at server end and using $("#dsr-data").html(dsrData) to display rows. But when I comment above line of code and put manual rows your code is working fine. Kindly help me to resolve issue (probably DOM issue). Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I got it why your code isn't working, let me update my answer

Comment: @Shubh - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Thanks a lot. Definitely your answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead.

```
<script>
   function uploadStatus(id) {
         alert('id =' + id);
   }

   function deleteStatus(id) {
        alert('id =' + id);
   }
</script>
```